# PostgreSQL constraint with Null Value

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

I have this table. I need to make combination of [seller_id, product_id, sold_out_date] unique, but the problem is

```
CONSTRAINT u_product UNIQUE (seller_id, product_id, sold_out_date)
```

doesn't work to stop duplicate rows due to NULL values. Making it as primary key will not work either, as it can't be NULL.

The reason why I need it to be unique is when product is sold out, `sold_out_date` will be entered, and when the product comes back in stock, I need to create a new row, so the combination of all three has to be unique.

After creating this constraint I want to execute query like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
(seller_id, product_id, sold_out_date)

VALUES (1, 'A', NULL)

ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead add an unique index like so and you will be fine

```
create unique index ux_indx on my_table(seller_id, product_id, coalesce(sold_out_date,'1990-01-01'));
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1e34861fb374d85edbf5dcebccaa7cda)*

in case you need to update on conflict :

```
INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES (1, 'A', NULL)
ON CONFLICT (seller_id, product_id, coalesce(sold_out_date,'1990-01-01')) DO UPDATE set sold_out_date = '2020-01-10';
```

Comment: i guess the ```ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING``` will be problematic with such index

Comment: @ИгорьТыра what problem? see fiddle

Comment: This works, thanks! What if I want to update some other attributes in other columns on conflict.  `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` ? DO UPDATE is asking for `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name`. How do I pass this index name here?

Comment: @Nihilist hmm in that case you can mention unique index columns in your conflict name, see updated fiddle

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! If possible can you please explain what coalesce is doing to make it work and if there is possible downside.

Comment: @Nihilist you are welcome , yes, The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not null. no downside in your scenario, just for replacig date  '1990-01-01' , make sure its something unique and never will inputed in your data

Comment: @eshirvana so coalesce(sold_out_date,'1990-01-01') means instead of NULL it is placing '1990-01-01' by default? if yes, why NULL is displayed in table?

Comment: @Nihilist yes, this is just for  unique index condition, we are not touching data in in table ,

Comment: whenever any cell in sold_out_date column is updated with real date, index will also update and replace '1990-01-01' with real date, correct?

Comment: Great! Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

try to use EXCLUDE

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT excl1 EXCLUDE USING btree (
    seller_id ASC NULLS LAST WITH =,
    product_id ASC NULLS LAST WITH =,
    COALESCE(sold_out_date, '2020-01-01') ASC NULLS LAST WITH =);
```

and `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` will work

Comment: `exclude` is much slower than `unique` , and behind scene make an index constraint for it.

Comment: yes, but it will work even after moving from ```ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING``` to ```ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT excl1 DO UPDATE SET...``` if needed in future

Comment: Thanks for reply. Its not working with DO UPDATE `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE not supported with exclusion constraints`

Answer (score 1):

It is a common practice in databases to use id's based on hashes, so you could create a hash on the combination of those three fields and use it as an id, then create a primary key constraint over this id field, e.g.

```
    INSERT INTO my_table
(seller_id, product_id, sold_out_date, id)
VALUES (1, 'A', null, encode(digest(concat('1','A',null) , 'sha1'),'base64'))
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

it is necessary that pgcrypto extension exists in your database, if don't use:

```
create extension pgcrypto;
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't try this but looks good. This may come handy in future.